# Auth as administrator

Tags: c#, admin, authentication

I've done an application that basically goes through all active users on a network via DirectoryEntry, where I'm able to get each computers Username (login id), this is done by DE.UserName (DirectoryEntry).

Alright, so far so good, now with my problem; whenever I try to fetch it's password it's throwing an exception saying I need to have admin rights in order to get the password of each connected pc.

I am not the owner of the network, so I'm wondering if there's any way to auth as an admin or change your group to Administrator, or in any way bypass this so I can access it's password?

Code:

```
 DirectoryEntry computers = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://JBVAS");//The domain
        IEnumerator enumerator = computers.Children.GetEnumerator();
        while(enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = enumerator.Current as DirectoryEntry;
            Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}{1}Password: {2}",
                entry.Username, Environment.NewLine, entry.Password);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use impersonation to make your code (temporary) run under a higher privileged user.

I wrote an easy-to-use impersonation class some years back, [you can find it over at CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx).

An example could be:

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
   // code that executes under the new context
}
```

Put your Active Directory code that needs administrator permissions inside the using block.

Comment: Won't that just give me the admin rights of this computer but not the network? Or is that what I'm looking for? I believe there is 4-5 admin accounts on the network, where they all have the userid "adm-[their name]", and us regular users just have our name as userid.

Comment: It would give you the rights of the user you specify. If it would be a domain administrator, you would run under this context, then.

Comment: I've added the code above, you believe if I put that under your using function, I will be authorised as a network admin and being able to grab their passwords aswell?

Thank you so much for your time!